# Angular 4 data binding concept

Tags: javascript, angular

I am creating an Angular app and need some help with the data binding.

I have a Dashboard where I have different Widgets. Every Widget has a name and a date.
To configure/change this settings I have created a Sidebar that can be shown. 
I am using a router to display the dashboard view. And the sidebar is not a children of the dashboard it is outside of the router.

When I click on the settings button on a Widget the Sidebar should open and should be able to show and change the settings of this Widget and than the Widget should run an update function.

I have already tried to work with a shared service but I dont think that this is the best solution because I have multiple Widgets each with different settings object.

Comment: Do you know about event emitter ?

Comment: Yes I know about the event emitter but I dont know if this is the best solution to do that because I have to use a shared service with the emitter and as I want to write the settings back after edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A shared service is a good call for this scenario, since you won't be able to bind to your click event in your `router-outlet` tag.

Let's say you have a component (pseudocode):

```
class MyWidget {
  widgetData: Object;
  constructor(private myService: MyService) { }
  handleClick(event) {
    this.myService.sendClick({event, data:this.widgetData})
  }
}
```

Then in your service, you can use a [Subject](http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html) to keep store the data that is needed for your `Sidebar` component.

Example service (psuedocode):

```
class MyService {
  subject = new Subject();
  sendClick(data) {
    this.subject.next(data);
  }
  getClick(data) {
    return this.subject.asObservable();
  }
}
```

Finally, your `Sidebar` will be able to [Subscribe](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/subscribe.html) to the `getClick()` method from your service:

```
class Sidebar {
  widgetData: Object;
  constructor(private myService: MyService) {
    myService.getClick()
      .subscribe(v => doSomethingWithWidgetData(v));
  }
}
```

For another resource: this [blogpost](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/12/01/angular-2-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject) has a good explanation of this concept.

Answer (score 1):

Shared Service is the way to go about the things over here , As there is no parent child Relationship Between Components you cannot use Event Emitters.
If you want to take things up a notch and go for a cleaner Design pattern go Ngrx Suite. It is tailor maid for such scenarios but keep in mind it will  reqire some additional dependencies and also bit more code.

Go for [**Ngrx**](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/ngrx) is the app is Large else stick to [**shared services**](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/faq).

Comment: How should I then implement the "wayback"? I mean that I want to write the change of the object back to the component which has sent the object. Should I subscribe to a new object after sending and unsubscribe again after all changes are done?

Comment: emit a new event and the Observing component can catch the event and update itself

Answer (score -1):

You cannot use Event Emitters since there is no relationship between two components, so ideal way would be to use is Shared Service.

Comment: Rather should have been a comment.